# Photo_view flutter photo wont show

Tags: flutter

My app was able to attach some picture and show it. I want the user to be able to see the image picture in full size so I'm trying to use photo_view but I'm not getting the result what I want. I used gesture detector to trigger the app so the image will open on tap. How can I achieve that?

> error: The argument type #NetworkImage or CachedNetworkImage# can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [tiket_kerja] lib\screens\main_pages\main_detail_ticket_page.dart:2785)

Here's my code:

```
GestureDetector(
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: ticketData[
            'picture_attachment_map']
        [
        'image_${index + 1}'],
    height: 150.h,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  onTap: () {
    print('Imaged clicked');
    PhotoView(
      imageProvider: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: ticketData[
        'picture_attachment_map']
        [
        'image_${index + 1}'],
        height: 150.h,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

As Error `can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider` It seems you have to use ImageProvider. In this case you have to replace `CachedNetworkImage` with `CachedNetworkImageProvider`

So your code should be like

```
GestureDetector(
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: ticketData[
            'picture_attachment_map']
        [
        'image_${index + 1}'],
    height: 150.h,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  onTap: () {
    print('Imaged clicked');
    PhotoView(
      imageProvider: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
        imageUrl: ticketData[
        'picture_attachment_map']
        [
        'image_${index + 1}'],
        height: 150.h,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it still wont work

Comment: Same error or something else?